# Convert JSON Data To Property Format using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, properties

I am working on one challenge which I am trying to solve, but due to lack of experience hit a roadblock. I would greatly appreciate any help from gurus on this site :)

I need to convert JSON input to property format.
**Example**:
Given JSON:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]}
```

Need to be converted to following format once script executed:

```
name="John"
age=30
married=true
cars.0.model="BMW 230"
cars.0.mpg=27.5
cars.1.model="Ford Edge"
cars.1.mpg=24.1
```

I found this online converter which works: https://tools.fromdev.com/json-to-property-converter.html

But because in my case i need to integrate to Azure pipeline, online version will not work for me

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe JSON booleans are supposed to be lowercase. What have you tried?

Comment: Answer below solved my problem. The goal of this was to automate azure pipeline deployment, so i can parse json and use it in variable sets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#jsonvarsubs

Answer (score 1):

This kind of format with the equals sign and no further punctuation is called `StringData` format in PowerShell and elsewhere.

PowerShell acutally already has a `ConvertFrom-StringData` function, but not a `ConvertTo-StringData` function.

However, we can make our own but it requires a few helper functions to do it.

I thought this was interesting so I took a stab at it today.

Here's what the calling function looks like:

```
Function ConvertTo-StringData($object, $propertyOverride){
    $fields = $object | get-member -MemberType NoteProperty
    foreach($field in $fields){
        if (IsArray($field)){
             OutputArrayMember -object $object -field $field
             
        }
        else{
            OutputMember -object $object -propertyName $field.name -propertyOverride $propertyOverride
        }
    }
}
```

It depends on these helper functions to work.

```
Function IsArray($object){
    $object.Definition -match '.*\[\].*'
}

Function OutputMember($object,$propertyName, $propertyOverride){
    if ($propertyOverride){
        "$($propertyOverride).$($propertyName)=$($object.$($propertyName))"
    }
    else{
       "$($propertyName)=$($object.$($propertyName))"
    }
     
}

Function OutputArrayMember($object, $field){
    $base = $field.Name
    $i = 0 
    foreach ($item in $object.$($field.Name)){
        ConvertTo-StringData -object $object.$($field.Name)[$i] -propertyOverride "$base[$i]"
        $i++
    }
    
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

[Here's the full code as a github gist, for posterity.](https://gist.github.com/1RedOne/ebd7147f377738694446064a7768deef)

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! I have a quick question: in there a way to get dot instead of square brackets? cars[1].mpg=24.1 => cars.1.mpg=24.1

Comment: Just figured it out. Made a small change here: ConvertTo-StringData -object $object.$($field.Name)[$i] -propertyOverride "$base.$i"

Comment: While testing found small issue. Code will not work if more complex json is used
```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SDSEmployeeMaster.ClientHandler[100]": "None"
    }
  }
}
```
Should return:
Logging.LogLevel.Default=None
Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft=Warning
Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime=None
Logging.LogLevel.System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SDSEmployeeMaster.ClientHandler[100]=None

Comment: If you know one or more properties are deeply nested, they will still work with this cmdlet.  Call it like this: `convertto-stringdata $json.Logging.LogLevel -propertyOverride Logging.Loglevel` .  You could use special handling like this to achieve your goal for anything nested more than two nodes.  Feel free to edit the code for your purposes

Comment: Thank you for quick response! In my case JSON structure is dynamic and i can not hard code values :(. I am trying to find a way to modify code so it can work on any Json and produce desired result. If i succeed i will share result here :)